# Same diagram, different line for the same series of data for new month's workdays (excluding weekends and holidays)

Tags: excel, diagram

We have a table where we keep track of our machine's performance. We made a diagram, where we see the machine's performance every workday cumulative. We established a standard/norm, that the machine works a 100% more then the previous workday. Every new month I copy the previous month sheet, then I delete the data and rewrite the dates to match the current month's workdays. I am excluding weekends and National Holidays.

When I did this with current month (July) I stumbled upon a very strange behaviour of Norma line in our diagram.

**This is June:**
[image]

The Norma (red line) is continuous, no breaks, no "staircase". It is just a straight line.

**BUT this is July.** I rewrote the dates to match with July's workdays.[image]

Weekends are exculded as well as from June's too, and it's a straight line. But in July's it's a "staircase" line (July 5th is a National Holiday).

When we entered June and I did the same thing with May and June. It worked, but with June and July this is what I ended up with. I know it has something to do with the dates, but I Just can't figure out what it is.

Like I said: in both cases weekends are excluded, but the same line is different. How can I make it so the Norma line is straight for July? Or is it easier to include weekends and holidays too and just write 0 for them?

Comment: Try copy-pasting the date coumns and "nomar line"-values in a separate sheet where you paste them as just values and make a line chart. What happens?

Comment: Copy-pasted both July and June into a completely new Excel file. It's still the same: July is "staircase", June is a straight line. Does it have to do with the format of the dates? Under Format cells it says that June has no formats, and July is set to Date. Also June is written in 01.06.2021 format and July is just 1.7.2021.

Comment: A little update: We have another workbook for another machine, with the same layout, diagram,dates etc. Copied the June sheet in that workbook, rewrote the dates for July and its working perfectly. The line is straight there.

Comment: Sounds like its the format. Does it work when you change the format of JUly to ``"Date"`?

Comment: It is set to Date. If it is set to Ordinary (I dont know in English, my Excel is Hungarian), it just shows the value of the date, like 44378 for 1.7.2021.

Comment: Problem solved, the axis type had to be set on TextFormat instead of DateFormat, and it works.